# Error appears on updating date format in datagridview

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have datagridview and use these code to update in database.
But I have problem in updating date in datagridview 
my columns date is (ra8,ra9)
these error appear when I try to update

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);


            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgRow in dgw.Rows)
            {
                string Id = dgRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                string Id2 = dgRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string isEdit2 = dgRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                string isEdit = dgRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                string isDelete = dgRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                string isADD = dgRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                string isADD1 = dgRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                string isADD2 = dgRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                string isADD3 = dgRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                DateTime isADD4 =Convert.ToDateTime( dgRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                DateTime isADD5 =Convert.ToDateTime( dgRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString());    
                string isADD6 = dgRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();

                string cb = "update ma3 set ra1='" + Id2 + "',  ra2='" + isEdit2 + "', ra3='" + isEdit + "', ra4='" + isDelete + "', ra5='" + isADD + "', ra6='" + isADD1 + "', ra7='" + isADD2 + "', ra8='" + isADD3 + "', ra9='" + isADD4 + "', ra10='" + isADD5 + "', ra11='" + isADD6 + "' where id='" + Id + "'";
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                con.Close();

            }                
        }
```

Comment: This is error coming from your calls to `Convert.ToDateTime`. What string are you passing in?

Comment: the string 26/12/2017 12:00:00 am

Answer (score 3):

Do not make use of `Convert.ToDateTime`, make use of `DateTime.TryParseExact;` and convert string in to datetime.

working with your formate using `TryParseExact` so your program not failed with exception , instead you can safely check conversion done or not by bool value

```
 string datestr = "26/12/2017 12:00:00 am";

    DateTime test = DateTime.Now;

   if( DateTime.TryParseExact(datestr, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null,
                    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out test))
    {
         //insert in db or proceed with input
    }
    else
    {
      //log and provide error message 
     }
```

Comment: give me for example (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: @m.mahmoud - please do accept upvote if works for you

Comment: ok i try these  DateTime isADD4 =DateTime.TryParseExact(dgRow.Cells[9].Value,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",null);

Comment: @m.mahmoud - as per fyou comment you have this formate " 26/12/2017 12:00:00 am" then formate string must be like "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"...and put that in if as i did so you can report back safe error rather than crasing you application

Comment: i dont find DateTimeStyles.None

Comment: @m.mahmoud - that exist under System.Globalization name space you do like this System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None or add using System.Globalization; in your cs file

Comment: sorry be patient with me i use these  DateTime test = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime isADD4 = DateTime.TryParseExact(dgRow.Cells[9].Value, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out test );

Comment: @m.mahmoud - is that not working ?? let me know what are you getting in dgRow.Cells[9].Value

Comment: string like these  26/12/2017 12:00:00 am

Comment: @m.mahmoud- then i must work code is working at my end ...seems like you missed something ...try my code in seperate console application...and it seems like it failing for other values ...as value given by you is working

Comment: mr @prany rana  i answer to my qusetion >>> i explain my code >>

Answer (score 0):

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {  con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);

                 foreach (DataGridViewRow dgRow in dgw.Rows)
                {
                     string id = dgRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); 
                     string date = dgRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                     DateTime  test;
                     string cb = "update date set date='" + DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out test) +  "' where id='" + id + "'";

                   con.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                   cmd.ExecuteReader();
                  con.Close();

             } 
}
```

> ok i try these code and these message appeare working Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: what is value of dgRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();??

Comment: i have datagrideview and update these date in columns >>datagrideview.Cells[1].Value.ToString();